# MATLAB plotting inequalities and division by zero

Tags: matlab, plot

I've a problem with MATLAB when plotting inequalities.
These ineq. involves symbolic substitution. However when X or Y are zero, there's a division by zero, so I needed to avoid calculating for those points.

```
tr=trace(A);
de=det(A);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(-1:0.1:1,-1:0.1:1); % Make a grid of points between 0 and 1
for i=1:length(X)
    for j=1:length(X)
    ineq(i,j)=0;
    if X(i,j) ~= 0 && Y(i,j)~= 0 
         ineq(i,j)=double(subs(tr, {a, b},{[X(i,j)], [Y(i,j)]}))<0 & double(subs(de, {a, b},{[X(i,j)], [Y(i,j)]}))>0;
    else
        ineq(i,j)=0;
    end

    j=j+1;
    end
    i=i+1;
end



scatter(X(:),Y(:),3,ineq(:),'filled')
```

The problem is that in the plot I can see blue dots on X and Y axis. Why is that? I thought that I enforced them to be 0 values.. What's wrong?
[image]

Comment: Isn't the colour the value of the dot? At least that's what `scatter` does by default.

Comment: @Adriaan But I expect them to be yellow points (0 values).. not blue ones..

Comment: What is the value at those `X,Y` locations? Also: you don't need the `else` statement, as you initially set your value to zero, and overwrite it in your `if` statement. Also it could have something to do with you plotting `double` instead of `uint8` (or some other integer type), unless your `double` ranges between `0` and `1`

Comment: You also don't need the `j=j+1;` and `i=i+1;`, they increase anyway, and are unaffected by this assignment within the loop.

Comment: Another correction: write `ineq = zeros(size(X));` befor the first loop to preallocate the memory for that, and delete all the `ineq(i,j)=0;` within the loops (including the `else`).

Comment: If you'll give an example for `A`, `a` and `b`, the problem may be reproducible, and you will have a higher probability of getting help.